# Switch Objects in Side Panel in CSS

Tags: css

I have two boxes within each of my member's profile page on my forum that I would like to switch.

Screenshot:

http://s22.postimg.org/69aqe1i29/panel.jpg

I want the "About" section below the "My Badges" section

is this possible within just CSS?

direct link to page in question: http://idenitties.com/vanilla/profile/3/test1

Comment: Why not just re-order the divs?  Put <div id="PeregrineBadges" class="Box PeregrineBadgesBox"> above <div class="Box About">

Comment: with pure css, i`m not sure. you can use Jquery to swap the sections(assuming that each section is within div tag`s).

Comment: You can do this just with CSS but you need to provide us the related HTML/CSS.

Comment: If I were you, I will do it by html. But, If you need to change the order of your div according to the member statut, you will have to create a copy of the two badges div. Then, just display the container div that you want according to the member statut

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reordering the HTML is your best option.  If this is generated content and you're unable to modify it in any way, you can use Flexbox to do reorder them.

http://tinker.io/9d3f8/1

```
.container {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -webkit-flexbox;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -moz-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -moz-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.about {
  -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 2;
  -moz-box-ordinal-group: 2;
  -webkit-flex-order: 1;
  -ms-flex-order: 1;
  -webkit-order: 1;
  order: 1;
}

<div class="container">
    <div class="about">
        About (first in source)
    </div>

    <div class="badges">
        Badges (second in source)
    </div>
</div>
```

The up side is that you don't need to know the sizes of either of the elements.  The down side is that browser support is limited:  IE10, Chrome, Opera, Firefox, Safari

http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to swap the `<div>` in the HTML but you can use a little absolute positioning to move the divs around.

For example this would work:

```
.about{
position: absolute;
width: 230px;
bottom: -30px;
}
```

But I would say the best option would be to just change the ordering in the HTML, simple copy paste.

Answer (score 0):

If box height is constant you may switch them using relative positioning. I mean you may shift top box to down for height of bottom box and otherwise.

```
.Box.About {
   position: relative;
   top: 114px;
}

.Box.PeregrineBadgesBox {
   position: relative;
   top: -178px;
}
```

Comment: after playing with CSS solutions it appears that only corrects it for each individual page, not for every page overall which may have larger/smaller photos, etc.

I will look into fixing this as suggested in html by reordering the div classes