# Need help changing order of boxes when screen resized

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Twitter Bootstrap to make a new website.  I am having an issue with the responsive side to this.

You can view my current site now:  http://www.monroeorm.com/SNOA/

When you resize the page the sidebars and primary content boxes aren't in the order I need them in.  When I resize the page, such as on mobile, sidebar1 shows up before the primary content.  I am trying to make it display after the content once the site is resized or viewed in mobile.

Here's what I've got so far:

HTML:

```
    <div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-3">
<div class="panel panel-info">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title">Sidebar1</h3>
              </div>
              <div class="panel-body">
                Sidebar1
              </div>
            </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="panel panel-primary">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title">Primary Content</h3>
              </div>
              <div class="panel-body">
                Primary Content
              </div>
            </div>
            </div>

<div class="col-md-3">
<div class="panel panel-info">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title">Sidebar2</h3>
              </div>
              <div class="panel-body">
                Sidebar2
              </div>
            </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:
http://www.monroeorm.com/SNOA/css/bootstrap.css

I'm probably making this harder than it seems - is there any way to get this achieved?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Switch Objects in Side Panel in CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15974264/switch-objects-in-side-panel-in-css)

Answer (score 1):

Is missing "col-sm-12 col-xs-12" on  declaration >> http://leoncio.me/dev/stack/20338694.html

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">

  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
     <div class="panel panel-info">
        <div class="panel-heading">
           <h3 class="panel-title">Sidebar1</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
           Sidebar1
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
     <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">
           <h3 class="panel-title">Primary Content</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
           Primary Content
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
     <div class="panel panel-info">
        <div class="panel-heading">
           <h3 class="panel-title">Sidebar2</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
           Sidebar2
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>

</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use [flexbox](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/) and then add a media query to reorder the divs when the browser width is a certain size.

Comment: could you explain better how flexbox can be used. For now this is a questionable answer. But description and code samples can help.

Comment: If they want a more detailed explanation they can use the link in the duplicate question thread which suggests the same solution.